# How to add a WYSIWYG editor to my module

Tags: module, editor

I'm developing a small Joomla plugin, but I can't figure out how to add a field that uses the normal Joomla article editor, and not only a text field. I have a field like this:

```
<field name="menu_one" filter="raw" type="textarea" default="" label="Field labbel" cols="100" rows="20" />
```

I would like to display a WYSIWYG editor like the `mod_custom` module does. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod-custom module seems to be using the code `<customContent />` to add the editor. It's located right before the `<files>` declaration in the XML file, not sure if it can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I actually found another option: The [editor field type](http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type).

```
<field 
   name="test1" 
   label ="Test Field" 
   type="editor" 
   width="300" 
   filter="safehtml" 
   editor="TinyMCE"/>
```

Using this field in my XML manifest, I'm able to add as many editors as needed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/customcontent-or-field-type-editor  explains the difference between <customContent />  and the editor field type  - added because Joomla Docs doesn't explain it (at least I can't find it there)